# Broadcast Receiver not working for me

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have the **AlarmMainActivity** which broadcasts an intent at a time set by the alarm. And the receiver program `AlarmReceiver` should catch this intent and send a notification. From the log, I can see that the alarm is being set, but the receiver doesn't start and its not working. Can you look at my code below and please let me know why the `BroadcastReceiver` is not working. Thanks.

**AlarmMainActivity:**

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_main);

        Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
           PendingIntent.getBroadcast
          (this,1,alertIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        final Button alarmButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.alarm_button);
        alarmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Long alertTime = new 
                GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+5*1000;
                Log.i(TAG,"Alarm will be sent at : "+ alertTime.toString());

                AlarmManager am = 
                (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alertTime,pendingIntent );

                Log.i(TAG, "Alarm is now set");
             }
        });
    }//oncreate
```

**AlarmReceiver:**

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";
    private String msgTitle, msgText, msgTicker;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Entered AlarmReceiver()");
        msgTitle = "Todays Weather";
        msgText = "Its Sunny and Warm";
        msgTicker="Alert";

        PendingIntent notifyIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, new 
         Intent(context, AlarmMainActivity.class),0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new 
         NotificationCompat.Builder(context).
                setSmallIcon(R.drawable.weather_image).
                setTicker(msgTicker).
                setContentTitle(msgTitle).
                setContentText(msgText).
                setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND).
                setAutoCancel(true).
                setContentIntent(notifyIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = 
           (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService
           (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1,mBuilder.build());
        Log.i(TAG,"Notification Sent");
    }
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thirdlaw.alertalarm" >

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".AlarmMainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <receiver android:name="com.thirdlaw.alertalarm.AlarmReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="MY_ACTION_STRING"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </activity>
    </application>

   </manifest>
```

Comment: did u register into manifest?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Or is it just not working?

Comment: @N5 Yes. I registered my receiver in the manifest. You can check the code for manifest above.

Comment: @Boss I am not getting any error. The receiver is not running. Its just for receiving the broadcast

Comment: i cannot see action of ur broadcast while starting intent ? can u plz specify this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<receiver />` tag out of the `<activity />` tag like :

```
    <activity
        android:name=".AlarmMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.thirdlaw.alertalarm.AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MY_ACTION_STRING"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I updated the manifest with the <receiver/> out of <activity/>. Now the receiver is getting the broadcast. Thank you. But the emulator is showing the msg "unfortunately, the process com.android.systemUI has stopped". But there are no errors. Can you pls help me with this problem

Comment: check the logs u must be having some log on emulator

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: in the emulator log it shows: 'com.thirdlaw.alertalarm(985)' 'system_process(425)'

Comment: Logcat:I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 109 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-04 02:41:22.920      975-975/com.thirdlaw.alertalarm I/AlarmMainActivity﹕ Alarm will be sent at : 1441348887931
09-04 02:41:22.940      975-975/com.thirdlaw.alertalarm I/AlarmMainActivity﹕ Alarm is now set
09-04 02:41:54.510      975-975/com.thirdlaw.alertalarm I/AlarmReceiver﹕ Entered AlarmReceiver()
09-04 02:41:54.570      975-975/com.thirdlaw.alertalarm I/AlarmReceiver﹕ Notification Sent

Comment: Dose the message still show now? Maybe it is just the problem of emulator. Try to run your app in a real phone.